# Did Stack Overflow read my mind?

Tags: discussion, suggested-tags

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976654/maven-doesnt-look-in-the-local-repository). When I was done typing, Stack Overflow's list of tag suggestions included [git](/questions/tagged/git), even though I did not mention Git at all in my question. As it happens, I am using Git to manage this project's source code. Did Stack Overflow read my mind and find this out, or is there another explanation?

Comment: Maybe [tag:git] is commonly used alongside [tag:maven].

Comment: I'm going to guess the word "repository" is associated with [tag:git] as a related keyword.

Comment: Was [tag:svn] and friends mentioned? If not, something else is up.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Among the words in your question, these (or some variation thereof) are relevant to the [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag:

> repository (4x), central, mvn (2x), project (4x), maven (4x), download, depend, package (2x), lang

(the word "lang" is there because you used a syntax highlighting override). To be precise, we run the words through a porter2 stemmer, so as far as the tag suggester is concerned, the words are "repositori" and "packag". Note that a word appearing in the title  counts as appearing twice.

For each tag/word combination, the tag suggester has a value that tells us how the presence of the given word in the post contributes to the probability that the post has the given tag.

For the [git](/questions/tagged/git) case and the above words, these are the values:

```
repositori  0.7034825
central     0.9293838
mvn         0.9776559
project     0.9789349
maven       0.988517
download    0.9982455
depend      1.000654
packag      1.002426
lang        1.005901
```

The smaller the value, the higher the increase in probability. Values greater than 1 mean that the presence of the particular word *decreases* the probability.

We multiply the values (with a factor appearing multiple times if a word appears multiple times, so the product contains the factor 0.7034825 four times). The result of this multiplication is about 0.191. This value is divided by a number that roughly represents how popular the tag is overall. For [git](/questions/tagged/git), this value is 1.0062.

We end up with 0.190. And this value is the tag suggester's calculated probability that your question should *not* be tagged [git](/questions/tagged/git). So the tag suggester's confidence that your question is about git is 81%, and the threshold for suggesting a tag to the user is 70%.

That's why it suggested this tag (which in this case was clearly a false positive).

---

A bit more about those numbers, if you care about such things: The top 5 predicting words for the [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag are

```
git     0.1789131
branch  0.4295278
repo    0.4700354
commit  0.5390894
diff    0.6549525
```

Even the words that have values larger than 1 are still pretty close to 1; you can interpret that as "The mere presence of a word is usually not enough to *exclude* a tag" (while on the other hand, the mere presence of some words does a lot for *including* one, like the word "git" appearing making that tag very probable).

So even the word with the highest value for the [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag, which is "column", only has 1.006.

The highest word/tag factor in the whole tag suggester database on Stack Overflow is 1.0937 for the word "gradle" and the tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). The highest value in a different tag is 1.0921  for the word "wpf" and the tag [android](/questions/tagged/android).

These values are biased towards popular tags and words, because only if

- you have *lots* of questions in a tag,
- *very few* of those questions containing the word,
- but *many* questions in *other* tags containing the word,

can you make any assumptions about a word decreasing that tag's probability. The word "gradle" [appears in 3,573 question bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3Agradle+is%3Aq), there are over 588k [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) questions, but only [10 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+body%3Agradle+is%3Aq) have both.

In closing, here are the top 10 predictors for the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag. Which one is not like the others?

```
attack  0.7576222
secur   0.819998
risk    0.8498669
trust   0.8828666
danger  0.8947973
flaw    0.9136809
applet  0.9166204
grant   0.9189128
encrypt 0.9257678
decrypt 0.9317889
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the *lowest* word/tag factor? Also, we always knew the truth about crapplets... `:P`

Comment: @michaelb958 The word is "emberjs" (actually "emberj" because of the stemming). The factor is 0.0132. I assume you can guess the tag :) The second lowest is 0.0233 for "linearlayout" and [tag:android].

Comment: [magic!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_%28information_retrieval%29)